# logstash cannot find log4j2.properties file

Tags: java, logstash

I have been trying to setup a proof of concept elasticsearch/kibana/logstash environment, but it is not working at the moment.

The LOGSTASH_HOME is:

```
c:\_work\issues\log4j_socketappender\logstash-5.0.1\
```

In the console log of logstash I found the following line:

```
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /_work/issues/log4j_socketappender/logstash-5.0.1/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs to console
```

You can see logstash is trying to look for log4j2.properties in the right  location but it does not contain the "c:" part

I tried adding the path to the config\jvm.options

```
 -Dlog4j.configurationFile=c:\_work\issues\log4j_socketappender\logstash-5.0.1\log4j2.properties
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I fixed it by adding the following line into **bin\setup.bat**

```
42.   SET JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dlog4j.configurationFile=%LS_HOME%\config\log4j2.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind:

Try specifying the full path with `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=c:\_work\issues\log4j_socketappender\logstash-5.0.1\log4j2.properties`

Also, is the properties file using [the new Log4j2 properties syntax](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties)? An old log4j 1.2-style properties file will not work. (Although I would expect a different error message in that case.)

Comment: That is what I tried, full path. Let me edit my question to avoid confusion. And the file was a log4j2 file.

Answer (score 0):

[as you can see here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/info-windows-logstash-and-could-not-find-log4j2-configuration/67633)

create an Environment Variable in Windows LS_SETTINGS_DIR and set it to:

```
        /c:/logstash-5.0.1/config
```

(notice - leading forward slash and all slashes are unix style not Windows style backslashes)

or to invoke logstash with

```
      --path.settings=/c:/logstash-5.0.1/config/
```

(again note position and direction of slashes)

I hope that this helps someone avoid the Googling and testing I have just done!