# Logstash: issue in pipeline starting

Tags: windows, logstash

I have installed ElasticSearch, Kibana, Logstash and Beats on Windows 7 64 bit system.
I am getting below mentioned error after executing 'logstash -f first-pipeline.conf --config.reload.automatic' command.

```
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /logstash-5.1.2/logstash     -5.1.2/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs to console
12:21:15.654 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.inputs.beats - Beats    inputs: Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5043"}
12:21:15.766 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline - Starting     pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125,    "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
12:21:15.839 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline - Pipeline main started
12:21:15.926 [[main]<beats] INFO  org.logstash.beats.Server - Starting server on port: 5043
12:21:16.544 [Api Webserver] INFO  logstash.agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9601}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in your *setup.bat* within your *bin* folder:

```
SET JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dlog4j.configurationFile=%LS_HOME%\config\log4j2.properties
```

But I don't see that it could harm `Logstash` from starting the pipeline. Unless you really need `log4j` to do the logging for you. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676294/logstash-cannot-find-log4j2-properties-file) could be helpful which elaborates pretty much the same. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of spaces in the path where Log4j2 is looking for the configuration file: `/logstash-5.1.2/logstash     -5.1.2/config/log4j2.properties`. Also the path starts with a slash so Log4j2 will interpret it as an absolute path.

You need to find the place where this is configured and specify the actual location of the configuration file. The logstash docs should have a logging configuration section.